# What is the difference between API key and Build Secret in Fabric.io?

Tags: android, fabric.io

I am using Crashlytics tool from fabric.io in an android app. I have put the API key in the manifest file. 
Fabric also provides a build secret string. But there is no instruction to use it. May be Fabric is assuming that users have prior knowledge about using BUILD SECRET.
 I have no idea what a build secret string is and where to use it in android projects. 
Can anyone tell me what is BUILD SECRET in Fabric.io and where it is used in android project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. The build secret is used when distributing your apps through Beta to ensure that only folks that have access to both the API key and build secret can distribute your apps. You can include the build secret in a Fabric.properties file that is referenced when distributing through Beta.